# jquery datatable sort plugin for date type mm/dd/yyyy hh:mmAM/PM

Tags: jquery, datatables

Really stuck on big problem. I need to sort a date column.But the date format is `mm/dd/yyyy hh:mmAM/PM. I tried till

```
jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oSort['uk_date-asc']  = function(a,b) { 
    var ukDatea = $(a).text().split('/'); 
    var ukDateb = $(b).text().split('/'); 

    var x = (ukDatea[2] + ukDatea[0] + ukDatea[1]) * 1; 
    var y = (ukDateb[2] + ukDateb[0] + ukDateb[1]) * 1; 
     console.log("here");
    return ((x < y) ? -1 : ((x > y) ?  1 : 0)); 
}; 

jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oSort['uk_date-desc'] = function(a,b) { 
    var ukDatea = $(a).text().split('/');
    var ukDateb = $(b).text().split('/'); 

    var x = (ukDatea[2] + ukDatea[0] + ukDatea[1]) * 1; 
    var y = (ukDateb[2] + ukDateb[0] + ukDateb[1]) * 1; 

    return ((x < y) ? 1 : ((x > y) ?  -1 : 0)); 
}
```

but now i don't have any idea how to include time .Please guys help me.

Comment: Coould be nice to see en axample of the input / columns. Is it mm/dd/yyyy hh:mmAM/PM with no space between mm and AM/PM? Like ...`12:56 AM` or `12:56AM` ??

Comment: Hey @davidkonrad. I am sorry but I couldn't give you screenshot right now as I am out of office...but its without space...eg 13/1o/2014 4:00PM

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the format is `mm/dd/yyyy hh:mmAM/PM`, then all there is needed for this format to be a [**`Date.parse()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse) compliant format is to insert a space between minutes `mm` and `AM` / `PM`. So if you do this, you can use the returned value from `Date.parse()` to compare the dates including the time :

```
jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oSort['uk_date-pre'] = function(a) { 
    a = a.slice(0,-2)+' '+a.slice(-2);
    var date = Date.parse(a);
    return typeof date === 'number' ? date : -1;
}    
jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oSort['uk_date-asc'] = function(a,b) { 
    return ((a < b) ? -1 : ((a > b) ? 1 : 0));
} 
jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oSort['uk_date-desc'] = function(a,b) { 
    return ((a < b) ? -1 : ((a > b) ? -1 : 0));
}
```

see demo -> **http://jsfiddle.net/ttfrxmsk/**

The following timestamps is used by the demo :

> 01/27/2011 10:20PM
>   01/27/2011 10:19PM
>   01/27/2011 10:19AM
>   10/13/2014 4:10PM
>   04/12/2011 11:20AM
>   10/13/2013 4:20PM
>   08/01/2012 10:20PM
>   07/10/2014 7:00AM
>   08/01/2012 10:20PM
>   07/10/2014 7:00AM

Comment: Thank you.It works but I have to typeof date === 'number' ? date : -1 and return date instead. But I have a question how does it it identify if its in mm/dd/yyyy or dd/mm/yyyy..Thanks again

Comment: You are welcome! I dont quite understand what you mean by "_It works but I have to typeof date === 'number' ? date : -1 and return date instead_" The idea is to return a number, even if `date.parse` fails, otherwise the function would return `NaN`.

Comment: @ntstha "_But I have a question how does it it identify if its in mm/dd/yyyy or dd/mm/yyyy_" I dont think `date.parse` can identify the different date formats, it just try to identify if the dateString matches any of the many formats it can recognize.

Answer (score 0):

I had to format and sort using mm/dd/yyyy format, so i had to do some changes...

```
 $("#tblSearch").DataTable({
        "processing": true, // for show progress bar       
        "filter": false, // this is for disable filter (search box)    
        "orderMulti": false, // for disable multiple column at once
        "bDestroy": true,
        "order": [[1, "asc"]],
        data: data,
        "columns": [
            


        ],
        "language": {
            "emptyTable": "We couldn't find any result for the search"
        },
        "columnDefs": [
            
            {
                data: "date", "sType": "date-mmddyyyy", className: 'text-center', targets: [0]
            , "mRender": function (d, type, full) {
                d = new Date(d);
                month = '' + (d.getMonth() + 1),
                    day = '' + d.getDate(),
                    year = d.getFullYear();

                if (month.length < 2)
                    month = '0' + month;
                if (day.length < 2)
                    day = '0' + day;

                return [month, day, year].join('/');
            }  }
        ],
    });
    jQuery.extend(jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oSort, {
        "date-mmddyyyy-pre": function (a) {
            var dateFormat = a.split('/');
            return (dateFormat[2] + dateFormat[0] + dateFormat[1]) * 1;
        },

        "date-mmddyyyy-asc": function (a, b) {
            return ((a < b) ? -1 : ((a > b) ? 1 : 0));
        },

        "date-mmddyyyy-desc": function (a, b) {
            return ((a < b) ? 1 : ((a > b) ? -1 : 0));
        }
    });
```